# Show that the matrix $(c{\bf A})^n= c^n{\bf A}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am being asked to show that given a square, invertible matrix $\bf A$, then $(c{\bf A})^n= c^n{\bf A}^n$ for all non zero $c$'s in $\mathbb R$.

I've tried just sort of writing down the definition of invertibility and playing a bit with that but it doesn't seem to be working. I think perhaps there's some basic property I'm missing.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Invertibility and being non zero have nothing to do with it. Do this inductively. Base case is trivial, and for inductive case just note that $(\alpha A)(\beta B)=(\alpha \beta) AB$. To show the latter, simply write down the definition of matrix product and scalar multiplication.

Comment: Might be invertibility is related as $n$ could be negative.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on avid19's answer: the only thing you would need is that $A$ is square. Invertibility and $c\neq 0$ have nothing to do with it (I'm assuming $n \in \mathbb{N} = \{1, 2, \dots, \}$).

**Hint** (not a complete solution): $$\left(cA\right)^{n+1} = \left(cA\right)^{n}\left(cA\right)=c^{n}A^{n}cA\text{ (why?)} = c^{n}cA^{n}A = c^{n+1}A^{n+1}\text{, } n \in \mathbb{N}\text{.}$$